# Incorrect Values When Reading Object Properies

Tags: javascript

I have an object that is displaying different attributes than what is being passed and I have no idea why this is happening.

[image]

The object is created when the script is first run and as I return objects from the database I return the updated object. When I am evaluating the properties of the object they do not match with what is being passed into my function, once I expand the object I see the property that matches with what was passed in but when I am reading it, it is completely different!

Has anyone else encountered this before?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdqtO.png

Comment: My guess is that you return the object *before* updating it from the database.

Comment: Can you take a snippet of your code?

Comment: Bergi was right. The object was being returned well before it was being updated. I was using forEach loops to evaluate the data. I modified it to use a for loop and adding in a variable to keep track of the count. I don't know why I didn't think of that sooner.